# Why selection sort is not working?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    int arr[5]={44,33,55,22,11};
    int i,j;
    for (i=0;i<=4;i++)
    {
        for (j=i+1;j<=4;j++)
        {
            if (arr[i]>arr[j]);
            {
                int k;
                k=arr[i];
                arr[i]=arr[j];
                arr[j]=k;
            }
        }
    }
    for (i=0;i<=4;i++)
        printf(" %d", arr[i]);
}
```

Output of the program is `11 22 55 33 44` and it should be `11 22 33 44 55`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try stepping through the code with your debugger ? Try it - it's simple and fun !

Comment: Is it your plan, for the rest of your career as a programmer, to post programs to StackOverflow every time there's an unexpected output?  The question you should be asking is **what are good techniques for finding bugs in programs?**, not **what is the bug in this program?**

Comment: The first technique you should learn is **turn on all compiler warnings** and **fix your program so that it compiles without warnings at all times.**  For this "stray semi" mistake, most compilers will tell you precisely where your bug is if you let them.

Answer (score 6):

Get rid of the `;` at the end of your `if` statement.  The swap is happening every time through the loop because it is no longer conditional.  You've implemented a very expensive version of "reverse".

Answer (score 1):

Remove `semicolon` after `if` loop :D

```
if (arr[i]>arr[j]);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int arr[5]={44,33,55,22,11};
    int i,j;
    for (i=0;i<4;i++){
        for (j=i+1;j<=4;j++){
            if (arr[i]>arr[j]){
                int k;
                k=arr[i];
                arr[i]=arr[j];
                arr[j]=k;
            }
        }
    }
    for (i=0;i<=4;i++)
        printf(" %d", arr[i]);
    return 0;
}
```